# JS that work on IE and doesn't work on chrome and FF

Tags: javascript

OK, that would be a really strange question indeed, but it really happened with me, I wrote a JS that work on IE yet, it doesn't on firefox or chrome.

I hope if someone could enlighten me with why this is happening...

My HTML code is the next

```
<h4>What kind of animals do you like the most?</h4>
<select id="animalName" name="animalName">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Which animal is it?</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Lion">Lion</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="otherAnimalNameDiv">
    <h4>As you picked the other, would you like to write it down to let us know?</h4>
    <input type="text" name="otherAnimalName" size="40" id="otherAnimalName" />
</div>
```

And my JS code is the next:

```
    var animalName = document.getElementById("animalName");
    var animalOtherName = document.getElementById("otherAnimalNameDiv");

    function animalSelect (){
        animalName.onchange = function (){
            if (animalName.options.value == "Other"){
                animalOtherName.style.display = "block";
            }
        };
        animalOtherName.style.display = "none";
    }

window.onload = function () {
    firstNameFunc();
    familyNameFunc ();
    emailAddressFunc ();
    passwordFunc ();
    rewritePasswordFunc ();
    colorPickerFunc ();
    animalSelect ();
    }
```

Why would it work on IE and wouldn't at Chrome or FF?....

When you select "Other" option from the select tag it's supposed to set a div display to block, that happens on IE but not FF or chrome.

Comment: Do you ever actually _invoke_ `animalSelect`?

Comment: You haven't really explained what doesn't work about your code. Also, it's not that strange that some JS code might work in one browser but not another. It's called [cross-browser compatibility](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross+browser+compatibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be willing to bet that the problem is your if-statement:

```
if (animalName.options.value == "Other"){
```

If you're trying to get the value of the selected option, you should try something more like this:

```
if (animalName.options[animalName.selectedIndex].value == "Other"){
```

Comment: Sorry, 8 seconds faster than you ;) Have a +1 anyway.

Comment: Awesome, it works now!! Thank you!
Do you mind explaining what happened? @_@

Comment: OKes, I get it now, got all figured ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to get the option value is wrong. It should be:

```
if( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "Other") {
```

Comment: He just added this to the question, but with the way he's calling the function (not as an event listener), you wouldn't be able to use `this`.